# Help with deploying Crystal Report embedded Visual Studio 2008 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have been trying to get around this error for a day now and have not had much luck.   I have a VS 2008 project that uses the embedded Crystal Reports which of course runs fine locally, but when deploying to my remote server the reports will no longer run.

I gathered that it was because I didn't have the right Crystal Reports components installed on my server.  So I attempted to add the dll files into my project directly which did work to resolve some of my errors but their is still a missing reference.

The missing reference is on the 'CrystalDecsions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' which is located in my GAC.

Is there anyway to get around this problem OTHER THAN installing the msi file on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with 2005 a while ago, the only way I was about to get around the problem was to install the crystal reports redistributable on the server.  Is there any reason that you're hesitant to install an MSI on your server?

Comment: I work for the good ole gov't and installing on the server takes small miracles.

Comment: OIC, try installing it locally and run a registry watcher / file system watcher to see what it does, then you can replicate that on your server.   But if you don't have permission to install then it's not likely that you'll have permission to correctly register DLLs or modify the registry either.